# Building a smooth function from a rapidly decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Is it possible to build a 1-priodic smooth function from a rapidly decreasing sequence such that the sequence be the Fourier coefficients of the function?
More precisely:

Let $\lbrace c_k\rbrace _{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ be rapidly decreasing sequence. Is it possible to show that there is a 1-priodic smooth function $F: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lbrace c_k\rbrace$ is the sequence of the Fourier coefficients of $f = F|_{[0,1]}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. (Assuming that that **rapidly decreasing** means that $\sup_{k\in \mathbb Z}\vert k^m c_k \vert <\infty$ for all $m=0,1,2,\dots$.)

The function must be $f(t)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z} c_k \exp(2\pi i k t)$.

Just write $f_N(t)=\sum_{\vert k \vert \le N} c_k \exp(2\pi i k t)$. As $\vert c_k\vert = O(k^{-2})$, this the sequence $(f_N)$ is Cauchy in $L^2([0,1])$ and thus $f=\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}f_N$ exists in $L^2([0,1])
$. Clearly $f$ is $1$-periodic and has the correct Fourier coefficients. I claim that it is also smooth.

Taking derivatives of $f_N$ produces powers of $k$, but they do not affect summability, as $c_k$ is rapidly decreasing. Hence the $k$th derivative $f_N^{(k)}$ is also Cauchy in $L^2$. Thus $(f_N)$ is Cauchy in the Sobolev space $H^k([0,1])$. This implies that $f\in H^k$ for every $k\in \mathbb N$ and hence it must be smooth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have question: if we define rapidly decreasing as for each $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is $d_N > 0$ such that for all $k \neq 0$ we have $|c_k| \leq \frac{d_N}{|k|^{N}}$, we answer is the same right? I mean these two definitions are the same thing?

Comment: I agree that the two definitions are identical.